# Drizzle component returns BigNumber

Tags: truffle, react

I am using the following **Drizzle (Truffle)** component to call a function from a smart contract:

```
<ContractData contract="Market" method="priceOf" methodArgs={this.props.id}/>
```

The result is a React Element that contains number in Wei: `4000000000000000`

Now, I am saving this in the state, and this is rendered when `this.state.price` is rendered. 
However, when I want to pass `{this.state.price}` as props `price={this.state.price}`, it does not work, the error message is that the React element can't be cloned.

Is there any way to get/parse/query/copy the raw data of the React Element? I need that `4000000000000000` as a number (`Number()` and `parseInt()` are giving `NaN`, `toString()` gives `[object Object]`)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is move away from the `drizzle-react-component` ContractData and go back to using drizzle to query contract state.

Using CacheCall to get contract state.

https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/getting-started/contract-interaction.

Answer (score 0):

ContractData returns a jsx-element and not a BigNumber. Just look in the code of ContractData. So requesting the value of the BigNumber which is a string, not a jsx-Element.

So the only way I think is feasable is to hack ContractData an pass it a handler that reads out the BigNumber. For this you need to break the api and add a new prop to it.

The other option is to write you own componet. It seems to be faster that.